# Fetching images from Gatsby src folder without Graphql, while still ALSO using Graphql for other images

Tags: javascript, json, gatsby, gatsby-image

I have a website, that has some old legacy html as a string, and the pages are setup as json files. So here is an example:

```
{
"textContent":"<h2>Hi!</h2><img src=\"../images/hello.jpg\" />"
}
```

So i have read, that you can in fact disable graphql for Gatsby, however there are some other components on the site, that makes great use of it, so I dont want to disable it entirely.

So to summarise:

I want to be able to point to images in my src folder from a string. Which I know might seem pretty oldschool, but there is a ton of these files, and I dont really feel like changing the structure, if I can avoid it.

Thx in advance!

Comment: I actually found a way to do it, making a folder called "static", in the root directory, will allow you to point to the image. Read more about the static folder in Gatsby here: 
https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/images-and-media/static-folder/

Answer (score 0):

Yes! The static folder is the correct way about this! I personally prefer to make my own image components for "above-the-fold" images - this way I can preload the images with a header tag and make my page load faster. It makes quite a bit of difference on the Google page Speed scores actually.